# TE = SD(P-B) doesn't look right?

Tags: statistics, variance

**Am I wrong? Why?**

Consider 3 time-series, Portfolio (P), Benchmark (B) and Excess (E), like so
$$P = \{ r_1, r_2, \dots , r_n \}$$
$$B = \{ s_1, s_2, \dots , s_n \}$$
$$E = \{ x_1, x_2, \dots , x_n \}$$
where $E = P - B$, or for the $i_{th}$ observation $x_i = r_i - s_i$.

Now, Tracking Error is evaluated as
$$ \delta(P,B) = \sqrt \frac{\sum_i^n (r_i - s_i)^2}{n} \qquad \qquad (1)$$

However, instead of $(1)$, I have noticed the practice of taking $ \delta(P-B) $, which doesn't make sense because

$$ \delta(P-B) = \delta(E) \\
\qquad \qquad \qquad\qquad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad
= \sqrt \frac{\sum_i^n (x_i - \mu_{E})^2}{n}  \qquad \qquad (2)\\
\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad
$$

Equations $(1)$ and $(2)$ measure 2 very different things. The former is variability of portfolio returns around a given benchmark and gauges active manager risk; however, the latter expresses variability of $E$ over $B$ around $\mu_E$ which doesn't hold much meaning for the intended purpose whatsoever. In fact, it  understates portfolio risk because, on balance, $\mu_E$ > $s_i$ and $ r_i - s_i > x_i - \mu_{E} $, which is a less volatile picture of relative portfolio returns.

Below is a manual decomposition to illustrate the difference for random sampled annualised monthly returns
[image]

Comment: Not sure what you are after here.  You are, of course, free to look at any metric you like.  May be worth noting that $\delta (P-B)$ vanishes if there is just an additive difference between the two time series.  That might be important if your two, supposedly correlated, series do not have the same mean.

Comment: @lulu, seeking clarification that $\delta(P-B)$, as a TE, is a flawed metric.

Comment: "flawed" is subjective. If one time series equals another plus some fixed spread, it is natural to say that they track perfectly. Your preferred metric lacks that property.

Comment: That's a good point, @lulu